# What does /* next to file names mean in a code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3, git-bash

I noticed some files have /* next to them in my code editor (`composer.json` and `style.css`. It looks like comment code... What does it mean?

EDIT - I am not talking about css comments. Please refer to the red outline on the left...

[image]

Comment: The css comments are my comments. I am talking about the file tree on the left guys...

Answer (score 3):

In CSS `/*` marks the start of a comment, while `*/` marks its end.

So everything between these two markers will be ignored by the CSS parser, but can be used to make the code more readable for a human being.

**EDIT**

This was a very stupid mistake to make, but I answered the wrong question.

The really questioned **file icon**, that looks like `/*` is typically used for files, that are human readable (in their text form) but don't have a "special" editor.